# Use of Hilbert basis theorem to find a lone generator for $I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

Let $I \subset \mathbb{C}[x]$ be the ideal generated by $\{x^n + n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. How do I use the proof of the Hilbert basis theorem to find a single generator for $I$?

Comment: Which proof?  There are several different ways to prove the Hilbert Basis Theorem.

Comment: I am quite puzzled by this question.  Already, $\langle x + 1, x^2 + 2 \rangle = \mathbb{C}[x]$ is the whole ring, so adding more generators makes no difference.  Are you sure the problem statement is correct?

Comment: You don't need to use the proof of the Hilbert basis theorem: $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is Euclidean, so you can just use the division algorithm.